# My app became unreachable after some time

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, ssl, domain, linode

I have an Vue.js app running on Linode at [strks.rs](https://strks.rs/) using Nginx

I am running it with nginx and I can not find any erros,

- nginx synatax is ok server is running and i tried flushing DNS and restarting nginx
- domain is active but it does not lead to my site
- only way I can reach site is https://192.46.234.237/ and go to advanced options and agree to proceed

I guess it is ssl error but I can't diagnose it, I installed mine using this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPPBO-QpiJ0&t=1s) and it worked fine for some time. I also tried renewing it manually but it is not yet due for renewal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your domain has been set as inactive by the domain registrar and removed from the DNS. From the whois record this took place on 19th January. Contact your domain registrar to find out more details and resolve the problem.

```
Domain name: strks.rs
Domain status: Inactive https://www.rnids.rs/en/domain-name-status-codes#Inactive
Domain status: serverHold https://www.rnids.rs/en/domain-name-status-codes#ServerHold
Domain status: pendingUpdate https://www.rnids.rs/en/domain-name-status-codes#PendingUpdate
Registration date: 29.12.2020 18:03:24
Modification date: 19.01.2021 00:55:19
Expiration date: 29.12.2021 18:03:24
Confirmed: no
Registrar: Serbia Broadband - Srpske kablovske mreže
```

Comment: It could not be I purchased it in December 2020, I just checked it is walid until dec 29th 2021, it says active on my domain provider

Comment: @idibegaj You're right, I did not read the whois record correctly. Something else is wrong because the domain is shown as inactive and serverHold. Most likely you did not [confirm the domain from the email link that you were sent](https://www.rnids.rs/en/national-domains/managing-domain-names). Contact your registrar to be sure why they have inactivated your domain.

Comment: Thanks, can I ask how you came to this information

Comment: @idibegaj Domain whois records are public information, though the identity of the registrant is often private. So I cannot see who you are, but I can see the registrar and the registered DNS servers. The field Confirmed seemed strange, so I did some searches and eventually found that special requirement from RNIDS.